# Node - display window when ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, load, document-ready

I am trying to show the window after the URL and everything inside that page is loaded. This is the script:

```
var loadWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        fullscreen: false,
        scrollbars: false,
        show: false
    })

    loadWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html')
```

What I tried:

```
loadWindow.on('ready', function(){
    loadWindow.show()
})
```

I also tried to `on('loaded')`, but none of these is working. What is the best solution to load a URL inside a page and display it only after everything is loaded?

Comment: `loadWindow.on('load'...)` I guess

Comment: I tried that too... It doesn't even display the window.

Comment: _It doesn't even display the window_ - what is the "it" that is supposed to show a window?

Comment: none of these events exist, here is the API: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md